# Rails devise user function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I execute a particular function after a user has signed up.
(I wanted to add to one of my associations, I already have it coded in a non-devise rails but now I need it here)

Comment: You have a lot of unaccepted answers for your previous questions. Maybe go over them and see if you could accept some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device has provided helper action '**after_sign_in_path_for**' you can override it within your application controller.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
.... #write your customize code or call any method
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For sign **up** it would look like:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if resource_or_scope.is_a? User  # and perhaps other conditions
    #... do something, go somewhere
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Ofc. Assuming that your Devise user model is called User.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after_create` callback in your User model.

The following guide has tons of examples: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html